# Moving the leap motion controller according to the ovr controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, leap-motion, oculus

I have an ovr controller which allows me to rotate the view around a room which I created in my scene. Recently I added a Leap Motion controller to my game. The problem is that the hands and their appear only in a part of the room. I want to attach the hands to the ovr controller just like the real person moving around with his hands always with him. The object the hands play with, a ball, and the room itself, have to stay at it place and the ball would be movable all around the room by the hands. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Leap Hand Controller (using ORION BETA, or HandController prefab using V2 Unity) prefab is attached to a camera object. Just assure to have both the LeapHandController and OVR prefab under the same Camera object. With this, both will move relative to the camera as father.

Answer (score 0):

Just attach it to the Left Camera if you are working with Cardboard.
Center camera if you are working with expensive HMD.